# PHP - Update Script not working

Tags: php

I have problem with update script, are something wrong with my script? beacuse whenever i run it, it just only show echo "ERROR". This my update script:

```
<?PHP 
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testuser");
    $choosed2 = $_POST['choosed2'];
    $creditnew = $_POST['creditnew'];
    $debitnew = $_POST['debitnew'];

    $newid = $choosed2 - 1;
    $bal = "SELECT balance FROM `bal` WHERE id=$newid;";
    $chek = mysqli_query($con,$bal);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chek);
    $old_balance = $row['balance'];
    if ($old_balance == NULL){
        $old_balance = 0;
    }
    $balancenew = $old_balance - $creditnew + $debitnew;
    $up = "UPDATE `bal` SET debit='$debitnew' credit='$creditnew' balance='$balancenew' WHERE id='$choosed2'";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$up))
        {
            echo "<div class='form' style='text-align:center; float:center;'><div style='font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; margin:10px'>UPDATE SUCCESS</div><br/><a href='index.php' style='margin:5px;' class='tombol'><< BACK</a><a href='Input.php' style='margin:5px;' class='tombol'>INPUT AGAIN</a></div>";
        }else{
            echo "<div class='form'><h3>ERROR</h3><br/><a href='balance.php'>Input again</a>";
        }

?>
```

info: `choosed2` is row id.

Anyone can help me? thanks.

Comment: Missing commas between the values. Besides, `ERROR` is a horrible way of knowing what's wrong. Use [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get proper error-messages. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: `SET debit='$debitnew', credit='$creditnew'` etc

Comment: 1. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after starting `<?php` and 2.  change else part like `else{
            echo "<div class='form'><h3>ERROR</h3><br/><a href='balance.php'>".mysqli_error($con)."</a>";
        }`

Comment: use the code of link:- https://eval.in/684449  . Also try to read prepared statement and use it in your code to prevent your code from `SQL Injection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed commas(`,`) in SQL statement. Your SQL query will be

```
$up = "UPDATE `bal` SET debit='$debitnew', credit='$creditnew', balance='$balancenew' WHERE id='$choosed2'";
```